# Function being executed when not being called

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I am working on this project where when a player clicks on a business and decides to purchase stock ( in `currency` form ) the money is deducted from the players balance and other stuff that doesnt really involve the problem i am facing. All is mostly functional, however, when a player interacts with multiple businesses then decides to select a business to buy from, it also processes the purchases of the other businesses that the player has interacted with.

For example, there are currently two businesses, `DX` and `DY`, they both sell stock at set prices. The player clicks on `DY` and decides to invest `$2`, the money is thus deducted from its account and all is good. The player then decides to click on 'DX' and invest `$2` again. The buying process goes through and the player gets the stock he bought, however, it also calls in the buying process for 'DY'. Instead of deducting `$2` from the balance, `$4` is deducted and `$2` worth of stock for both 'DY' and 'DX' is added.

I assume its from my 'eventListener', I made an attempt to resolve this problem by changing the id of the element shortly after interaction but that didn't work. Any help?

Last Edit: The element change upon selecting a business works and is required in order for the entire thing to work.

`Modal` Code

```
 <div id="myModal" class="modal fade">
                <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="closeBackground">
                        <span class="close" onclick="CloseModal()">&times;</span>
                    </div>
                    <p class="insideModal" id="EditInside"></p>
                    <div id="updater"><input class="InputBuy" id="UserBuys" placeholder="0"><input type="submit" id="a"></div>                
                    <p class="ValueInsideModal" id="RateInsideModal"></p>
                    <p class="ValueInsideModal" id="PriceInsideModal"></p>
                    <p class="ValueInsideModal" id="ValueInsideModal"></p>
                </div>
                </div>
```

Input ID

```
            var sbmt = document.getElementById("a");
```

Modal Onclick for DX

```
            function op1() {
            $('.modal').css({
                display: 'block'
            });
            $('.modal-content').css({
                left: '0px',
                opacity: '0'
            }).stop(true, true).animate({
                left: '555px',
                opacity: '1'
            }, 'slow');
            change.innerHTML = "DX";

            var buybtn1 = sbmt;
            buybtn1.id = "buybtn1";

            ModalRate.innerHTML = "Rate: " + DX.Rate + "%";
            ModalPrice.innerHTML = "Price: $" + DX.Price + " AUD";
            ModalTotal.innerHTML = "Total Owned Stock: " + DX.Amount + "";

            buybtn1.addEventListener('click', purchaseDX);
            //buybtn1.onclick = purchaseDX 

            due(Player.TotalEquity);
            sub(Player.UserBalance);
        };
```

`Modal` Onclick for `DY`

```
            function op2() {
            $('.modal').css({
                display: 'block'
            });

            $('.modal-content').css({
                left: '0px',
                opacity: '0'
            }).stop(true, true).animate({
                left: '555px',
                opacity: '1'
            }, 'slow');
            change.innerHTML = "DY";

            var buybtn2 = sbmt;
            buybtn2.id = "buybtn2";

            ModalRate.innerHTML = "Rate: " + DY.Rate + "%";
            ModalPrice.innerHTML = "Price: $" + DY.Price + " AUD";
            ModalTotal.innerHTML = "Total Owned Stock: " + DY.Amount + "";

            buybtn2.addEventListener('click', purchaseDY);
            //same goes for DY

            due(Player.TotalEquity);
            sub(Player.UserBalance);
        };
```

**BuyProcess**

```
function purchasebusiness() {
let x = Player.UserBalance;
let y = business.Amount;
let AmountEnteredPrice = document.getElementById("UserBuys").value;
let UpdatedProfile = Processbuy(AmountEnteredPrice, business.Price, x, y);
Player.UserBalance = UpdatedProfile[0];
business.Amount = UpdatedProfile[1];
ModalRate.innerHTML = "Rate: " + business.Rate + "%";
ModalPrice.innerHTML = "Price: $" + business.Price + " AUD";
ModalTotal.innerHTML = "Total Owned Stock: " + business.Amount + "";
due(Player.TotalEquity);
sub(Player.UserBalance);
sbmt.id = "a";
```

};

I also intend on adding like 10 more businesses.
Edit: added a declared variable I forgot to add in

Another Edit: I know exactly what the problem is

When a player starts fresh ( refreshes the page etc ) and clicks on a business, the set data and values that are assigned to that business are presented. This includes the buy button.

Let's say that a user wants to invest into a business like DY and currently has DX open. He clicks off DY and clicks on DX to open the modal page. When he clicks on DX, the button that is assigned to that modal changes its ID from `a` to `buybtn`. I had originally thought that if I change the ID of the button, it would only process the one that has its ID assigned to it.
'it did'

The user then enters in the value $x to buy $x amount of stock from DY. When the user presses submit, the process of buying stock succeeds, however, somehow, $x worth of DX stocks will also be bought.

I do not know much about how 'addEventListeners' work but it has somehow tagged the input element in html, disregarded the changing IDs, and process both of them like a for loop iterating from 0 - dx amount of businesses.

I don't know how to make it only process the business that is selected.

Comment: despite all this code, the stuff we need to see is missing. Specifically this button you're changing ids on. First off, don't do that. Also, with more than one business, you might be better off not using element ids (since they all have to be unique) and instead use class names or data-attributes and make your jquery selectors relative to a root element - or find another way to relate element logic to the business it is operating for. My 2 cents...

Comment: I can't be sure without seeing the code in full context, but this sounds like some sort of event bubbling/propagation bug

Comment: In both functions there is `sbmt.id = "a"`, then in *op1* there is `var buybtn1 = sbmt` and in *op2* there is `var buybtn2 = sbmt`. So it seems both *buy* methods are attached to the same button.

Comment: Using an ID is fine. You really should reduce the code to the minimum that demonstrates the issue. As it is, it's impossible to debug code that doesn't run and is missing the parts that likely have the issue.

Answer (score 2):

Hope this will help you to change the logic. I tried to make it as simple as possible:

```
function purchase(company) {
    let business=window[company];
    let x = Player.UserBalance;
    let y = business.Amount;
    let AmountEnteredPrice = document.getElementById("UserBuys").value;
    let UpdatedProfile = Processbuy(AmountEnteredPrice, business.Price, x, y);
    Player.UserBalance = UpdatedProfile[0];
    business.Amount = UpdatedProfile[1];
    ModalRate.innerHTML = "Rate: " + business.Rate + "%";
    ModalPrice.innerHTML = "Price: $" + business.Price + " AUD";
    ModalTotal.innerHTML = "Total Owned Stock: " + business.Amount + "";
    due(Player.TotalEquity);
    sub(Player.UserBalance);
}

function showMarket(company) { // to replace with OP1, OP2, OPblablabla
    if (window[company]){
        alert('Company not found.');
        // closeModal();
        return;
    }
    let business=window[company];
    $('.modal').data('company',company);
    $('.modal').css({display: 'block'});
    $('.modal-content').css({left:'0px',opacity: '0'}).stop(true, true).animate({
        left: '555px',
        opacity: '1'
    },'slow');

    change.innerHTML = company;
    ModalRate.innerHTML = "Rate: " + business.Rate + "%";
    ModalPrice.innerHTML = "Price: $" + business.Price + " AUD";
    ModalTotal.innerHTML = "Total Owned Stock: " + business.Amount + "";
    due(Player.TotalEquity);
    sub(Player.UserBalance);
};


$('#a').on('click',function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    purchase($('.modal').data('company'));
});
```

Then you have two way to use it, with a class using a listener and some data

```
<a class="show-market" data-company="Amazon" href="#">buy amazon</a>
<a class="show-market" data-company="Qantas" href="#">buy qantas</a>
<script>
$('.show-market').on('click',function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    showMarket($(this).data('company'));
})
</script>
```

or just with a link

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="showMarket('Amazon');">buy amazon</a>
```

Comment: `"javascript:void(0);"` is so last millennium. *void* is an operator, not a function so `void 0`. Using links as buttons is poor form, use a button. :-)

Comment: I come from last millennium dude ;)

Answer (score -1):

I have changed

```
addEventListener('click', function)
```

to

```
elementid.onclick = function
```

When I was debugging one of my selling features of my game, I noticed that one of my variables were not being declared with the elementid.

The problem I had was:
Upon buying stock from many businesses and attempting to sell them, the sell feature would sell the other businesses stock instead of the selected businesses stock.

I looked at how my code behaved after processing through one of the 'undeclared' variables. Instead of skipping through or presenting itself with a runtime error, it stepped into another businesses selling function and sold that businesses stock. I do not know why it did that, but I think it has to do with the nature of these Listeners.

Comment: An answer that contains only code and not even complete one (the first piece of code is all but self explaining) doesn't help the community. Plus if I was you I would prefer @Vixed's approach, when using JQuery `$('.show-market').on('click', function (e) {})` is the way to go

Comment: I was experimenting with different listeners from ww3 schools, I dont actually know why it works all I know is it just works? 
( Like I explained in the question I knew that the problem was from the event listener, thats why I was messing around with different methods of onclick execution, if that makes sense )
The answer provided simply simplified the code, which i am grateful for, but didnt really fix the problem